# Confusion with Alloy.createController in Titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm a new coder and I'm trying to interpret the Titanium code below:

```
var settings = Alloy.createController('settings');
```

What exactly is a "Controller" and when is it used? How would a "settings controller" differ from an object titled "settings"?

Any help would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read [Alloy Controller](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Controllers)

and [This](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Alloy.Controller)

This will give you proper understanding of controller. 
The setting you defined in `createController` function refers to the js file named `settings` while settings is just an object in any file.. But you should avoid using the same names (not necessary because sometimes it creates problems.) .

Comment: I would also add to read up on the MVC - model-view-controller design pattern. It's what Alloy is based on.